# OTF, TTF font cmap table

Tags: php, gd, truetype, opentype

I have managed to get the `cmap` from the OTF file, which looks like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
  ["tableVersion"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["version"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
  ["cmap_format_4"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (3) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["platformID"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["platEncID"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["language"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      ["map"]=>
      array(222) {
        [0]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["code"]=>
            string(4) "0x20"
            ["name"]=>
            string(5) "space"
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["code"]=>
            string(4) "0x21"
            ["name"]=>
            string(6) "exclam"
          }
```

Now, I need to generate character map using PHP GD or any other way. PHP GD preferred, though. How do convert letter in format 0x21 to something that would look like letter?

Comment: You might want to check the different Unicode CMAPs of the font to see if they aren't different. For instance, if you're looking at the Windows CMAP but FreeType uses the Apple CMAP and the latter happens to be broken, then some glyphs would be unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to draw the characters on to an image using the font definition.

Have a look at the definition for [imagettftext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) - trying to perform the rendering yourself from glyph outlines is not advisable.

Comment: I mean, I use this information only to get available glyphs in the font. Now I need to convert them to a letter and print them out.

Comment: I can get some values simple by using `chr()`, but it won't work with say `0x2da`.

Comment: Guy: From the documentation linked above: `"May include decimal numeric character references (of the form: &#8364;) to access characters in a font beyond position 127. The hexadecimal format (like &#xA9;) is supported. Strings in UTF-8 encoding can be passed directly."`

Comment: @Orbling: I have tried that with `0x17e` character (zcaron). I have tried it this way: `imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, 'font.otf', '&#x17e;');` but it didn't work (produced empty image).

Comment: @Guy: The OTF format is the problem, [look at the following message](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#85552).

Comment: @Orbling: His suggestion is not very pertinent. Is can anyone think of a way avoiding this [the conversation of OpenType to TrueType?] and just someway fixing `0x17e` to work with `theimagettftext()`.

Comment: @Guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152033/accented-characters-not-showing-when-using-imagettftext-with-otf-but-showing-with

Comment: Is there a workaround that you could suggest? Say using external code to generate charactermap (image) from what I have?

Comment: @Guy: When GD fails me, I turn to ImageMagick, there is a section on [using UTF8 text](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode) with it on the documentation.

Comment: CFF table of an OTF font consists the whole glyphs images/programs. You can draw them as geometry objects. It is NOT POSSIBLE draw whole collection of the glyph by php api, because php api is using ENCODING parameter to call the glyph, but not the INDEX or NAME of the glyph.

Answer (score 0):

CFF table of an OTF font consists the whole glyphs images/programs. You can draw them as geometry objects. It is NOT POSSIBLE draw whole collection of the glyph by php api, because php api is using ENCODING parameter to call the glyph, but not the INDEX or NAME of the glyph.